# Where does the root of spring-mvc application come from?

Tags: spring-mvc

I created a simple Spring MVC project in STS according to [this tutorial](http://duckranger.com/2011/07/spring-mvc-3-0-with-sts-tutorial-part-i/). When run it on server, the "Hello World" page was displayed under this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/goodproject/
```

My question is, where does the root url "`/goodproject/`" come from? The top-level package is `com.duckranger.goodproject`, is this the reason? May I use a different name as the url root?

In duckrabger's tutorial, the project name was used as the url root (from the screenshot). But in my case, using project name resulted a 404 error.

Comment: I've got the answer from [another question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705685/springsource-ide-does-not-use-project-name-as-root-url-for-spring-mvc-applicatio

Comment: What Application Server are you using?

Comment: VMWare vFabric tc server

Comment: check your web.xml file, or your finalname in pom. Maybe the server is getting this names to put in your root context.

Answer (score 0):

if you package your application in an EAR, you have an application.xml that defines the context-root of any web app. (which is generated from the EAR project POM if you use Maven)

If you deploy WARs directly, it depends on the application server : you may have specific xml configuration that defines the context path for each application.
For example, Jetty uses a context.xml file.