# Spring MVC base/root URL is the same with war name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, url

I created a basic rest service using Spring MVC with xml config. My app name is: **myservice**. When i create a war from it, I receive a war named **myervice-1.0.0**. In conclusion, I have to access my application through **http://localhost:8080/myservice-1.0.0/resource**. I'd like to be just 'myservice', like project name. What can I do? Thanks a lot. I'm using tomcat + gradle.
    **web.xml:**

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>webappservice</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>webappservice</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: App Server? Glassfish/tomcat? Which one. Show your web.xml too please

Comment: Are you using eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename the war name. If you are using maven as build tool. Then you can use below solution.

```
 <build>
      <finalName>myservice</finalName>
     . . .
    </build>
```

It will better if you can share some configuration details like pom.xml,web.xml etc.

Comment: I'm using gradle, and my web.xml is above.

Comment: you can specify the war name in build.gradle .                                                  `war.archiveName "myservice.war" `                                                                                        Check for reference: [https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War%3aarchiveName]

Comment: war.archiveName "myservice.war" worked for me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you double click on the server definition in STS, you will see a "modules" tab. From there, you can edit the "Path" and set it to whatever you want. When you select "Run on Server", STS has to define a context path and simply defaults it to last element of the default package. If I recall correctly, by default Tomcat uses the file name name of the zipped or exploded .war. In either case, you can over-ride it.

[see more about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705685/springsource-ide-does-not-use-project-name-as-root-url-for-spring-mvc-applicatio)